# Handle multiple sublink depths with php with little or no mod rewrite dependency

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a content management system and have hit a snag while trying to develop seo friendly urls. I am using php to handle urls, however I have a problem when I try to get the REQUEST_URI for more than one depth level. I am trying to avoid using .htaccess to handle this, because I would like the system to be fairly easy to set up on IIS/nginx/etc also and do not want it to be apache dependent any more than is necessary.

I have in my htaccess file

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

and then in my php I have a class that handles the REQUEST_URI slug by checking to see if a record exists in the mysql database. This works fine if the request is something like

```
http://example.com/foo
```

however throws an internal server error if the request is

```
http://example.com/foo/bar
```

This seems to occur even if I have a completely blank index.php, so I suspect the answer must be at the htaccess level. How can I get my system to handle multiple REQUEST_URI depth levels? Do I need to use a mod rewrite regex or is there a less apache dependent solution?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I needed to change my .htaccess rule from

```
FallbackResource index.php
```

to

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

The missing slash was causing the error. -.-

Comment: I thought about deleting this, but in case anyone has a similar derp, I'm going to leave it up so perhaps they will stumble across it, have a snicker at my expense and move forward with their project.